# Function call not responding

Tags: python, function, printing, call

I have defined a countdown function but when I call it nothing happens.  Without the function call the code works.  How is my function call wrong?

Also the `print()` function gives me invalid syntax for end='\r'.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import time
def countdown(t):
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timeformat, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
   t=30
   countdown(t)
   print("Goodbye!")
```

Comment: I've got the print syntax error figured out.  I had to add "from __future__import print_function.  Also had to import sys to flush the buffer after print.  I still don't know why my function call doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with addition of "import sys & import os" plus the use of sys.stdout.flush() after the print statement.